# (bazel) Specifying __BAZEL_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR__

Tags: macos, bazel

`__BAZEL_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR__` seems to default to using the iPhoneSimulator instead of MacOSX on my Macbook Pro? What is the elegant way to set this? Can I specify this in my bazelrc? I sure hope I don't have to write my own CROSSTOOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this is because you're building an `objc_library` at the top level, which defaults to platform ios. You can either depend on the library via a platform-specific top level rule (such as `apple_binary` with `platform_type="macos"`") or specify these flags at the top level:

`--cpu=darwin_x86_64
--apple_platform_type=macos`

Don't write your own CROSSTOOL for this.